# jQuery UI resizable - event trigger on minWidth, maxWidth, minHeight, maxHeight exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, events, jquery-ui-resizable

I can not find an event that notice me when the `min`/`max` limits are reached or exceeded in the API documentation.

Is there an option to do it, without checking the limits by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, your only option is to manually check whether the `min`/`max`limits are reached or not. You can use the `size` property of the `ui` object passed to the [resize event](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize) callback to access the current width and height, and the [`option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#method-option) method for accessing the `min` and `max` values.

---

```js
$(function () {
    $("#resizable").resizable({
        minWidth: 50,
        minHeight: 50,
        maxWidth: 250,
        maxHeight: 200,
        resize: function (event, ui) {
            var $elm = ui.element;
            if (ui.size.width <= $elm.resizable("option", "minWidth"))
               console.log("Reached Min Width!");

            if (ui.size.height <= $elm.resizable("option", "minHeight"))
               console.log("Reached Min Height!");

            if (ui.size.width >= $elm.resizable("option", "maxWidth"))
               console.log("Reached Max Width!");

            if (ui.size.height >= $elm.resizable("option", "maxHeight"))
               console.log("Reached Max Height!");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#resizable {
    width:100px;
    background:dogerblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/css/jquery.ui.resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/css/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
     <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

---

<sup>Anyway, it'd be nice to have that option: I've created a [Feature Request @ jQuery ui](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10647).</sup>